# creating graph with raw data - Python - Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to show the Average Order Value across various months within a graph.
The raw data is stored within a variable called ikdf, and contains the following columns:

```
Invoice Number, Invoice Date, Product Name, Invoice Quantity, Item Amount
11241, 24/07/2020, Batten Strip, 10, £29
11241, 24/07/2020, Perimeter Band, 6, £57
11283, 01/08/2020, Iso Strip, 34, £168.30
```

If it isn't 100% clear, the 'Item Amount' column is the line total for that product.

Firstly I changed some of the columns to numeric.

```
ikdf['Invoice Quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(ikdf['Invoice Quantity'])
ikdf['Item Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(ikdf['Item Amount'])
```

I then added a 'Month' column.

```
ikdf['Month'] = ikdf['Invoice Date'].str[3:10]
```

The 'Month' column for July orders just shows 07/2020

I am trying to find out the overall revenue from the invoices per month, and then divide that number by the amount of invoices in a given month, which would produce an Average Order Value for each month.
My attempt is below, but I don't think it is the quickest way.
AOV just stands for Average Order Value.

```
Jul2020 = ikdf.loc[ikdf['Month'].str.contains('07/2020')]
rez = Jul2020.groupby('Invoice Number').sum()
rezz = len(rez)
av = Jul2020['Item Amount'].sum()
aov = av / rezz
Jul2020_AOV = aov

Aug2020 = ikdf.loc[ikdf['Month'].str.contains('08/2020')]
rez = Aug2020.groupby('Invoice Number').sum()
rezz = len(rez)
av = Aug2020['Item Amount'].sum()
aov = av / rezz
Aug2020_AOV = aov

Sep2020 = ikdf.loc[ikdf['Month'].str.contains('09/2020')]
rez = Sep2020.groupby('Invoice Number').sum()
rezz = len(rez)
av = Sep2020['Item Amount'].sum()
aov = av / rezz
Sep2020_AOV = aov

months = (Jul2020_AOV, Aug2020_AOV, Sep2020_AOV)
months:
Out: (625.55133640553, 889.1805421686745, 704.4039790575916)
```

Is there a quicker way that I can group / split the data for individual months?
I would then be able to show a visualization of this for all months.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Please can somebody point me in the right direction?

Another example of something I tried before posting here can be seen below:

```
months = [month for month , df in ikdf.groupby('Month')]

plt.bar(months, ikdf['Item Amount'].sum() / len(ikdf.groupby['Invoice Number'].sum())
plt.xticks(months)
plt.ylabel('AOV per month')
plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.show()
```

This did not show any difference between months, but showed the average order value for the whole dataset.
Picture of the output is here:
[AOV for the months combined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woIXD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `datetime` type:

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice Date']).dt.month

plot_data = df.groupby(['Invoice Number', 'month'])['Item Amount'].sum().unstack('month')

plot_data.plot()
```